# Mock HttpContext.Request.Cookies in Asp.Net Web Forms

Tags: cookies, mocking, httprequest, httpcontext

I am looking for the best way to mock HttpContext.Request.Cookies in Asp.Net Web Forms.

Following is my code:

```
public void Method1()
{
    var _cookie = this.Context.Request.Cookies["PersonID"];
    if (_cookie != null)
    {
        //some code.........
    }
}
```

Below is part of my Test method code:

```
using (var httpSimulator = new HttpSimulator("/", @"c:\inetpub\").SimulateRequest(new Uri(request), form))
{
 //some code
  var aObject= new ClassA(HttpContext.Current);
  aObject.Method1();

}
```

I am not sure if we can mock cookies for HttpRequest.
Please help.

Many Thanks In Advance,

Thanks,
Kan

Answer (score 0):

Your quickest solution is to wrap HttpContext with a wrapper class. But you can only get away with this if the methods return a scalar value or an object via its interface.

So IF it returns a non mock-able object, your screwed.

From my experience, the best way to achieve a high percentage of testable code is to layer your app. In this case you would want to LAYER UP all usages of HttpContext. That means to use HttpContext on the UI layer (code behind or view). You would have to sacrifice testability (mockability) on these upper layers.